# python google spanner hangs when used with locust

Tags: python, python-multithreading, locust, google-cloud-spanner

```
from google.cloud import spanner
import locust

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = spanner.Client()
    query = "select * from table where id=@id"
    params={"id": "testId"}
    param_types={"id": spanner.param_types.STRING}
    with client.instance("instance").database("database").snapshot() as snapshot:
        snapshot.execute_sql(sql=query, params=params, param_types=param_types)
```

this will hang on the snapshot line. anyone know how to solve this

Comment: I have no idea whether spanner is gevent-compatible (if it isnt then it will never work with locust). But try just moving the import of locust to the top (which in turn imports gevent, which monkey patches pythons IO calls, which should always be done as early as possible)

Comment: How do you use or implement locust? It seems that there is an issue importing locust dependency.

Comment: @Cyberwiz I tried switching import line and it's stuck

Comment: @RobertG it's stuck from just importing locust, without even using it. can you point me to the issue, was not able to find anything related to spanner + locust

Comment: I am currently using Google Cloud Shell and installed locust by entering `pip3 install locust`. Error is  `Unable to import 'locust'`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently, and the Spanner library does seem to conflict with `gevent`.

I was able to force it to "work" by excluding thread patching in gevent, though of course I don't know what else breaks.

To test it yourself, in Locust [__init.py__](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/locust/__init__.py#L11), you can change this line:

```
monkey.patch_all()
```

to

```
monkey.patch_all(thread=False)
```